# How to use server response after a form is submitted

Tags: javascript, php

I have to use a simple form to retrieve a token from a server.  I then need to use that token to create a unique link for a user session.  I have the following sample code to generate the token page:

```
<form id="token" action="whatever.php?name=joe&hobbie=fun" method="POST"></form>
<script>
    document.getElementById('token').submit();
</script>
```

This automatically takes me to the page that has the token on it as a text string.  I just need to figure out how to get that text as a variable I can use.

Comment: Are you asking how to implement server-side functionality in `whatever.php`?  How to fetch the token in code without refreshing the page?  Something else?  It's not really clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In your handler for `whatever.php`, you're redirecting the user to a new page and then rendering some HTML. You can pass the token along as a query parameter on the new page, and then grab that from javascript if you need to store it and use it locally.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) shows you how to retrieve a value off the query string.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot for whatever reason add the token to the page as a hidden value in the following example:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" name="token" id="token" />
```

Then please use AJAX for this with the following logic (All based off your code):

- Have a server side script which produces the token lets call this page `token.php`
- Send to `token.php` a `post` request using AJAX with your variables for generating the token (Seems like you send `name` and `hobby`)
- Receive the token from the scripts response and use it as you would like

An easy and simple AJAX tutorial can be found here http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/